# Automatically login a user after signup in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a Spring WebFlux app, where login and signup functionalities are both working well. The login has been implemented using the `UserDetailsService`, where we have a domain class that extends `UserDetails` and an `@Service` that knows how to find a user, given a username.

Although the signup flow works, the user needs to go login right after signup, as opposed to being directly logged in after signup.

My question is, does Spring provide something like a `login` method, that takes a `UserDetails` object, and sets up session such that that user is logged in? If no, can I get some pointers on where I can get started to implement something like this?

For context: I'm posting this question after researching to the point of digging through spring-security's source code as well, and turning up empty.

Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: Spring security login page configuration:

```java
.and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(Url.LOGIN_URL)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .requiresAuthenticationMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, Url.LOGIN_URL))
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .authenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
```

Comment: What type of application do you have? is a SPA? or SSR? Could you show us your spring security configuration?

Comment: It's a SPA that makes a request like `POST /users` to sign up a new user, after which I want to log the user in. I've add the login page configuration in the question, is that what you meant by security configuration?

Comment: Well I mean the whole config, but I think that is enough for now. Are you using sessions with SPA? If yes, are you persisting them somehow? Also, what is the result of your authentication process (creating a session, returning a token, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, the sessions are saved to an in-memory redis instance. The result is that a session is created (implicitly by Spring, I believe) and a session ID is returned to the client in the form of a cookie. There's no other token besides this session ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I don't know webflux but I wanted to give it a go this morning so go easy on me if this is not how things are done in webflux. I just took a sample app, added `sign-up/{newUserName}` endpoint, that will not only register the user but will login as well.

```
    @GetMapping("/sign-up/{newUserName}")
    public Mono<String> signUp(@PathVariable("newUserName") String userName, 
                               ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        UserDetails newUser = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username(userName)
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        customMapReactiveUserDetailsService.addNewUser(newUser);

        return exchange.getSession()
                .doOnNext(session -> {
                    SecurityContextImpl securityContext 
                                    = new SecurityContextImpl();
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, 
                                   null, newUser.getAuthorities());
                    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                    
                    session.getAttributes()
                        .put(DEFAULT_SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTR_NAME, 
                             securityContext);
                })
                .flatMap(WebSession::changeSessionId)
                .then(Mono.just("You can now go to /secured without login"));
    }
```

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration {

       @Bean
       public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) 
       {
          return http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/secured").hasRole("USER")
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public CustomMapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
           // There are no registered users at this point
          Map<String,  UserDetails> users = new HashMap<>();
          return new CustomMapReactiveUserDetailsService(users);
        }
     }
```

- Signup is very simple as it is not the purpose of this demo, it is done via `GET http://localhost:8080/sign-up/{newUserName}`.
- A new user with username `newUserName` will be created with password as `password` and role `USER` and that user added to the map of registered users.
- I think only this point matters for your question. When logging in normally `AuthenticationWebFilter` will call `securityContextRepository.save(exchange, securityContext)` to save the context if the login is successful. But it is too late for the request filters as I am in signup controller now so I just replicate that behaviour in the controller method for signup. But this could be done in a **response path** of a web filter that applies only to `sign-up/{newUserName}` but I am not familiar with the webflux filter mechanism. This is because on the response path of `sign-up/{newUserName}`, you will know if the signup is successful and the user already exist at that point in the database so it is just about replicating the login behaviour.
- Github repo

  https://github.com/kavi-kanap/stackoverflow-63030967

**Update**

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter.java#L133
- Above code only replicates only the login part. i.e `securityContextRepository.save(exchange, securityContext)` but if it was a normal login, `this.authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(webFilterExchange, authentication)` would have been invoked as well as you see in the spring security source code. Since you have custom `authenticationSuccessHandler` see, if you can invoke that too depending on what it does.

Comment: Thank you Kavithakaran, this helped me move forward. In my case I'm using the `ReactiveSecurityContext` so I had to do it a bit differently. That and with a few other things, I managed to get this working, thanks in big part to your detail here. Now, when a new user signs up, the login happens automatically. However, it appears that the authentication success handlers are not invoked. So, I have two questions: one, quoting you, "I just replicate that behavior", can you point to where the source in Spring for this is? Two, how do I get the authentication success handlers to be invoked?

Comment: You are right. I have not replicated that behaviour fully. I have updated the answer pointing to the source code

Comment: Actually do you mind updating the question with your custom `authenticationSuccessHandler` code?

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer. I ended up calling my custom success handler myself after logging the user in, but was wondering if there was a better solution. Awesome dude, thanks a ton for your insights.

Comment: This is what spring security would have done anyway. But the current issue is your controller logic is littered with code that belongs to a spring security web filter. May be it is not a big issue if you extract that code a specific class but still invoked from controller.

Comment: But Have a look about how to add a custom web filter to spring security chain.  1) When you implement that filter, make sure it only applies to `signup` url and otherwise not invoked 2) Make sure it is the last filter in the chain so even though it is the last one on the request path, it will be the first one on the response path 3) Move the logic you have here to that filter on the response path ( ie the path after  `chain.filter(exchange)` inside the filter

Comment: Yes! That's the kind of solution I was hoping to arrive at. Have to still figure that out though. I'll look up, thanks for the pointer man!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, seems like you are using a redis to store the sessions, but in your login configuration there is no `.securityContextRepository()` specified, you should specify one in order to store in redis the sessions (this ask your first question).

To automatically login a user, you could do the following:

1. As you have a SPA application, in your `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` (I guess that you are generating the session ID, if not, is not a problem either) you could redirect the user to your home, then your frontend router could redirect the user to the page (component) that you want where a user should be redirected when registers an account, you could do this manually or through [RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java).
2. When you reach that page (component), you could check (with backend) if the user has a valid session stored in cookies, if yes, show everything, if not, redirect to the home with an alert or something like this.

Comment: Thank you Nico. If I understood this right, the client is expected to make two requests for this to work, one for the actual signup, and the other to create the login session. But, if having the client make two requests for this flow is okay, the second request might as well be to the `LOGIN_URL` right? The client obviously has the password since they just signed up. I'm looking to avoid that and do this flow in the single sign-up request. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes you could do it as you describe (two client requests), but it is possible to do it in only one (that requires more work in the backend). When a user makes a signup you could create a session and return it as cookie in the response of that signup, the way that you implement this is up to you, you could call the login in the signup or you could just create the session, with this way everything is in the server side. But yes, you understood correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm stuck. The *you could call the login in the signup* is what I'm trying to figure out. It doesn't look like spring-security exposes a single `login(userDetailsObject)` that does this, is there? If not, can you advice on where I should start looking to do something like that?

Comment: Yes, you could inject your `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` that I guess is `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` and then call the `authenticate()` method (you should know how to create the `Authentication` object), then if eveything goes well you can call to your securityContextRepository and create the session and store it. Another solution could be making an HTTP call directly to your login endpoint.